# finding missing digits using divisibility rules

Tags: elementary-number-theory

find the missing digits of 33^15=$x9938945498y6542054345z$

**My Attempt**:I have found that $z=7$ because its like the first digit of $3^3$. But I cannot find $x$ and $y$. Which divisibility rules should I use?

Comment: Divisibility by 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is divisible by both $9$ and $11$. Since $x$ and $y$ are digits of different parity, this allows you to determine them:

\begin{align}
x+y+113&\equiv0\mod9\;,\\
x-y+58-55&\equiv0\mod11\;,
\end{align}

where $113$ is the sum of the remaining digits, $58$ is the sum of the remaining digits that have the same parity as $x$ and $55$ is the sum of the remaining digits that have the same parity as $y$. So

\begin{align}
x+y&\equiv4\mod9\;,\\
x-y&\equiv8\mod11\;.
\end{align}

Since $x$ and $y$ are decimal digits, this leaves the options $x+y=4$ or $x+y=13$ and $x-y=-3$ or $x-y=8$. Since $x+y$ and $x-y$ have the same parity, we must have either $x+y=4$ and $x-y=8$ or $x+y=13$ and $x-y=-3$. The first option doesn't yield decimal digits, so the second option is the only solution, yielding $x=5$ and $y=8$.

Comment: You state, $\quad$ *Since x and y are digits of different parity, this allows you to determine them:* $\quad$ I gave an answer using mod $13$ and mod $7$ not knowing in advance that it would even work! What is the underlying theory for your answer (elaborate on parity)? Is there underlying number theory that guarantees I won't be left 'holding the bag' by jumping into it the way I did?

Comment: @CopyPasteIt: I basically use the same digit sum method as you do – as your table states, the block size for $11$ is $1$, so I add even-numbered digits and subtract odd-numbered digits. By "parity" I mean whether a digit is even- or odd-numbered. So it's a bit simpler with $11$ (also because the result is divisible by 11, so we don't need Fermat's little theorem to get the remainder modulo $11$), but you can also do it with $13$.

Answer (score 0):

Divisibility by 9 will give you information about $x + y + z$.  So will the divisibility by $11$ test. Can you use those?

Comment: Yes I know about them but we cannot find them just with two rules

Comment: Yes, you can.  If z = 7 then the divisibility by 11 rule gives you $x - y = k; k \pm 11$ and the divisibility by 9 rule gives you $x + y = j; j \pm 9; j \pm 18$.  That should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

1) Divisibility by eleven means the sum of the even digits minus the sum of the odd digits is a multiple of eleven.

So x9938945498y6542054345z divisible by 11 means

x + 9 +8 +4 + 4 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 0 + 4 + z = 9 + 3 + 9 + 5 + 9 + y + 5 + 2 + 5 + 3 + 5 + 11k

So

x + z = y + 55 - 47  + 11k

x + z = y + 8 or x + z = y - 3

2) Divisibility by 9 means the sum of the digits is a multiple of 9

So x + 9 +8 +4 + 4 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 0 + 4 + z + 9 + 3 + 9 + 5 + 9 + y + 5 + 2 + 5 + 3 + 5 = x + y + z  + 102 = x + y + z + 9x11 + 3

So x +  y + z is 6 more than a multiple of 9.

So x + y + z =6 or x + y + z = 15 or x + y + z = 24

3) $33^{15} \equiv  7 \mod 10$.  (You figurde that out.)

So z = 7

Put those 3 together and you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Recall some [Stupid Divisibility Tricks](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/divisibility/StupidDivisibilityTricks.pdf),

[image]

The OP has left the following problem to be solved,

$\tag 1  10^{22} x +  10^{11} y + 9,938,945,498,065,420,543,457 = 33^{15}$

Applying the $\text{mod}(13)$ operator while using the 'trick', we calculate

$\quad 10^{22}  \text{ (3 block alt sum)} = -10  \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$
$\quad 10^{11}   \text{ (3 block alt sum)} = -100 \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$
$\quad 9,938,945,498,065,420,543,457 \equiv$
$\quad \quad \; -9+938-945+498-065+420-543+457  \text{ (3 block alt sum)} = 751 \equiv$
$\quad \quad \; 10 \pmod{13}$

To calculate $33^{15} \pmod{13}$ we'll use Fermat's little theorem,

$\quad 33^{15}  \equiv 2^{15} 10^{15} \equiv 2^{3} 10^{3} \equiv 5 \pmod{13}$

Putting all this together we get

$\tag 2 3x + 4y \equiv 8 \pmod{13}$

The fun part now is that we can reuse some of the above work while applying the $\text{mod}(7)$ operator,

$\quad 10^{22}  \text{ (3 block alt sum)} = -10  \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$
$\quad 10^{11}   \text{ (3 block alt sum)} = -100 \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$
$\quad 9,938,945,498,065,420,543,457 \equiv$
$\quad \quad \; -9+938-945+498-065+420-543+457  \text{ (3 block alt sum)} = 751 \equiv$
$\quad \quad \;  2 \pmod{7}$

To calculate $33^{15} \pmod{7}$ we'll use Fermat's little theorem,

$\quad 33^{15}  \equiv (-2)^{15} \equiv (-2)^{3}  \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$

Putting all this together we get

$\tag 3 4x + 5y \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$

Working with the two equations...

The digit pair $(x,y)$ solution set $A$  for $\text{(2)}$ is given by

$\quad A = \{(0,2),(2,7),(3,3),(5,8),(6,4),(7,0),(8,9),(9,5)\}$

The digit pair $(x,y)$ solution set $B$  for $\text{(3)}$ is given by

$\quad B = \{\color{red}{(0,5)}, (7,5), \color{red}{(1,0)}, (8,0), (1,7), (8,7), \color{red}{(2,2)}, (9,2), (2,9), (9,9),$
$\quad \quad \quad \; \,\color{red}{(3,4)},\color{red}{(4,6)},\color{red}{(5,1)}, (5,8), \color{red}{(6,3)}\}$

Since $A \cap B = \{(5,8)\}$, we've found the answer to OP's question using divisibility rules.